# Lead Owner Change to User/queue are firing validation rules incorrectly

Tags: validation-rule, user, queue, lead-assignment

I have two validation rules

1. For lead owner change to 'user'
2. For lead owner change to 'queue'

Here, user validation rule is firing, even though I am changing the owner to queue. How to make system understand queue/user change?

User Validation Rule:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED( OwnerId ) ,
    $Profile.Name == 'Partner Community for GA Admin',
    Owner:User.Contact.Account.Parent.Name <> $User.CompanyName
)
```

Queue Validation Rule:

```
AND(
    ISCHANGED( OwnerId ) ,
    $Profile.Name == 'Partner Community for GA Admin',
    NOT(
        CONTAINS(Owner:Queue.QueueName, "Inside")
    )
)
```

Comment: `Owner:User.Contact.Account.Parent.Name <> $User.CompanyName` the left hand side of this expression is NULL which is not equal to `$User.CompanyName` hence first VR fires.

Comment: ALL Queues have ID's that start with 00G So you then check if the Owner.Id contains or Begin with 00G

Comment: @MegheshShenoy Great! That helped..Thanks